# Autofill login information for a site inside web browser control in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to make an windowsphone 7 application.
The user will store his login details inside the app and on opening of the app,the app will login into the specific site by filling the details automatically.This site I am referring doesnt have any APIs for logging.

The app will need to autofill the  details which requires javascript injection...
Has anybody work on this liness?

Comment: you can just store so small amount of data in `isolated storage`

Answer (score 0):

You can use IsoltedStroageSettings for such a small purpose since you need only a couple of fields to store.
A simple example would be

```
IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

to initially add the values

```
appSettings.Add("id", "sum@somthing.com");
appSettings.Add("password", "pass123");
```

to retrieve them later

```
string id= (string)appSettings["id"];
string id= (string)appSettings["password"];
```

Hope that helps :)